# ignore file parser deploy

Tags: parse-platform, deployment

there any way to ignore files or file paths when you have multiple folders deploy parse that I should not raise such node_modules folder and others can?

I found these links which have the same question but the answer is not very clear

https://www.parse.com/questions/ignore-files-on-deploy

https://www.parse.com/questions/ignore-files-on-deploy--2

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find documentation for it but it looks like parse have added support for a .parseignore file as evidenced by the code here https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/blob/master/parsecmd/deploy.go#L29.

It looks like supports most of the .gitignore syntax except ** using the [github.com/facebookgo/parseignore](https://github.com/facebookgo/parseignore/blob/master/parseignore.go) library.

While it appears to work for a small number of files, it is choking on my node_modules directory with a 'too many open files' error.

Comment: Jamie McCrindle're right there are many files in the node_modules bower_components part and what I did was just get the files needed to run the application and make deploy.Voy to read the documentation thank you very much for your answer. Cheers